# printing specific values from a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to print specific values inside a dictionary.

```
my_dictionary = {'url': 'www.google.com', 'value': [{'car': 'Mercedes', 'engine': 'Gas'}, {'car': 'Audi', 'engine': 'Diesel'}, {'car': 'Volkswagen', 'engine': 'Hybrid'}]
```

Expected outcome: `Gas, Diesel, Hybrid`

```
for x in my_dictionary:
    y= my_dictionary['value'][0]['engine']
    print(y)
```

Above is my code but it gives me back: `Gas Gas`

Comment: You need to iterate over the *list* at `my_dictionary['value']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`my_dictionary` has two keys, so `x` will successively be `'url'` and `'value'`. And then you're not actually using your iteration variable in the print statement, just printing from the first element of `value` both times.

You need to actually iterate over the entries in the `'value'` list.
What you intend looks like this:

```
for entry in my_dictionary['value']:
    print(entry['engine'])
```

Comment: what if I wanted to change key `car` to key `model` for example?

Comment: @Mediterráneo That wouldn't affect this code at all, seeing as how you're not interacting with the `car` key in any way here.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the previous answer, this may be a good candidate for list comprehension:

```
print([entry["engine"] for entry in my_dictionary["value"]])
```